# How to read the content on an exception raised by a third party app in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, exception, django-models, django-rest-framework

Need help in a situation. I have made a request to a third party app and it is raising an exception so i  want to read message of this exception

```
exceptions.AlreadyExistError : Reason = Entered bank Account is already registered:: response = {"status": "ERROR", "subCode": "409", "message": "Entered bank Account is already registered"} request_id  = fdd54b5c25c73cc3d437188278b0be26



try:
        add_beneficiary = Beneficiary.add( bankAccount=order.payee_bank_account_number)
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) #Reason = Entered bank Account is already registered:: response = {"status": 
                  "ERROR", "subCode": "409", "message": "Entered bank Account is already registered"} 
                   request_id  = c57d9df21bd413d9a46eaec82a590e9b
```

How do I read the message of the exception

Comment: Just remove that try except to get the full stack trace of the error. That blanket catching `except Exception as e` is also not a good practice as there are many different errors that can happen yet you catch _all_ of them.

Comment: `print(str(e))` will print the exception message

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat actually I need to catch the error because on the basis of that I have to execute other task in except block so I just want to extract the message some how to make comparison.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I have tried that but it is printing the exact thing what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AmitYadav Are you trying to get the value of `request_id` ?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi no I am trying to get the data of response in that, specifically message.

Comment: @AmitYadav Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you can use regular expressions to match the response in json format, then parse it to get message

```
import re, json

exception = str(e)
result = json.loads('{' + re.search('{(.*)}', exception).group(1) + '}')
message = result['message']
print(message)
```

OUTPUT

`> Entered bank Account is already registered`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AmineMessaoudi it worked perfectly.